# Print barcode in bluetooth thermal printer in Android

Tags: android, image, printing, bluetooth

I'm working on an android project that must print a receipt for every transaction it make. As of now, I can print text on a bluetooth thermal printer using this code.

```
  public void printSample() {

        String str = "";
        str += "THIS IS A SAMPLE PRINT" + "\n";
        str += "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" + "\n";
        str += "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" + "\n";
        str += "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" + "\n";
        str += "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" + "\n";
        str += "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" + "\n";
        str += "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" + "\n";
        str += "\n\n\n\n";

        printNormal(str);
    }

 public boolean printNormal(String text) {
        byte[] format = {27, 33, 0};

        boolean isPrintSuccess = false;
        if (mmOutputStream == null) {
            return false;
        }
        try {
            mmOutputStream.write(PrinterCommands.INIT);
            mmOutputStream.write(format);
            mmOutputStream.write(text.getBytes(), 0, text.getBytes().length);
            isPrintSuccess = true;
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return isPrintSuccess;
    }
```

I've tried printing barcode from my drawable resources. See code below.

```
public void printImage() {
    Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.barcode);
    Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

    try {
        mmOutputStream.write(byteArray,0,byteArray.length);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "NullPointerException " + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IOException " + e.toString());
    }

}
```

But, I didn't get the right result.

Hope you can help me in this circumstance.

[image]

Comment: You need to look at the printer documentation.  The way those printers typically work is you send an escape code that means "print a UPC bar code" then you send the UPC digits after that. For example, your `byte[] format` array starts with 27, which is the ASCII Escape character.  There's probably a different format that starts with 27 that tells the printer to print a bar code instead of characters. What model/manufacturer is the device? If I can find docs online, I might be able to show you how to do this.

Comment: @krislarson i'm using epson tm-p20.

Comment: what kind of bar code do you have to print?

Comment: I did find this:  https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=72 Does that help at all?

Comment: @krislarson barcode128.

Comment: The marketing docs say code 128 is supported, but I don't see any commands for enabling code 128 on the chart I found online.  The technical manual I would need to look at comes on the CD included with the product (which I don't have), or can be found on the Epson business partners website, which requires a login.  So unfortunately I can't access the information I would need in order to help you.